# How to compare an user input to a text file using BufferedReader

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

So I'm working on a project that requires me  to compare a users input to a list of words in a txt file. I've been trying to compare the the input as a string to the BufferReader, but it hasn't been working. Any suggestions is welcomed

Here's the code for the project

```
public class Lab5Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("fileName");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        /** In order to read a text file that is inside the package, you need to call the actual file and then pass it
         * to the BufferedReader. So that it can be used in the file**/


//        String[] wordArray = { "hello", "goodbye", "cat", "dog", "red", "green", "sun", "moon" };
        String isOrIsNot, inputWord;

        // This line asks the user for input by popping out a single window
        // with text input
        inputWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word in all lower case:");

        // if the inputWord is contained within wordArray return true
        if (wordIsThere(inputWord, br))
            isOrIsNot = "is"; // set to is if the word is on the list
        else
            isOrIsNot = "is not"; // set to is not if the word is not on the list

        // Output to a JOptionPane window whether the word is on the list or not
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The word " + inputWord + " " + isOrIsNot + " on the list.");
    } //main

    public static boolean wordIsThere(String findMe, BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {

//        for (int i = 0; i < bufferedReader.lines() ; i++){
//            if (findMe.equals(theList[i])){
//                return true;
//            }
//        }

        while((findMe = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (findMe.equals(bufferedReader.readLine())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }  // wordIsThere
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the function to check if the word exists. Each line being reader from the text file is not being checked with `findMe`. Made these changes, it works.

```
    public static boolean wordIsThere(String findMe, BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        for (String word = br.readLine() ; word != null; word = br.readLine()) {
            if (word.equals(findMe))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In method `wordIsThere`, parameter `findMe` is the word you are looking for. However you overwrite the value of the parameter with the line read from the file.

You should declare a separate variable to store the line of text that you read from the file.

```java
public static boolean wordIsThere(String findMe, BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException {
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); // read first line of file
    while(line != null) {
        if (findMe.equals(line)){
            return true;
        }
        line = bufferedReader.readLine(); // read next line of file
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also note that since you are using `JOptionPane` to get user input, a separate thread is launched and this thread does not terminate when method `main` terminates. Hence you should call method `exit`, of class `java.lang.System` in the last line of `main`, in class `Lab5Program1`. Otherwise, each time you run class `Lab5Program1` you will start a new JVM that will not terminate.

For console applications, you can use class [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get user input.

```java
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a word in all lower case: ");
String inputWord = stdin.nextLine();
```

Also consider closing files when you have finished with them. In your case it is not necessary since the file is automatically closed when the JVM terminates.